# How do I convert a string in C++ or C to an integer array?

Tags: c++, c

How do I convert a string into an array of integers? Can I use `sstream`, because `atoi` doesn't work?!

Comment: I think you should give few examples of desired input/output to make it more clear

Comment: k .. suppose der is a no 110011000 stored in a string i want to store it in a vector array !! as numbers how to do it

Comment: You want to convert binary stings to integers?

Comment: So the elements of vector would be {1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0} ?

Comment: kasperasky, i think you should elaborate on what you want more precisely. i'm quite sure what i told you is *not* what you want :p

Comment: Could you please explain how exactly atoi "does not work"? Compile-time error? Coredump? Result different from expected? Also, please provide an example of string and the expected contents for the vector.

Comment: I thought this question was clear until I read this mess of comments.

Answer (score 5):

As you said in the comments, you got a binary string and you want to convert it into integers. Use bitset for that:

```
std::istringstream is(str);
std::bitset<32> bits; // assuming each num is 32 bits long

while(is >> bits) {
    unsigned long number = bits.to_ulong();
    // now, do whatever you want with that long.
    v.push_back(number);
}
```

If you only have one binary number in that string `str`, you can get away with

```
unsigned long number = std::bitset<32>(str).to_ulong();
```

Converting that in C is also possible...

```
long value;
char const *c = str;
for(;;) {
    char * endp;
    value = strtol(c, &endp, 2);
    if(endp == c)
        break;

    /* huh, no vector in C. You gotta print it out maybe */
    printf("%d\n", value);
    c = endp;
}
```

`atoi` can't parse binary numbers. But `strtol` can parse them if you tell it the right base.

Comment: boost::dynamic_bitset if it's a variable sized length

Comment: greg, std::bitset takes care of that. it stops at the first whitespace when reading. tho you have to give a max width. but he wants to convert to a integer anyway. so i think setting it to sizeof(long)*CHAR_BIT should do it.

Answer (score 4):

How exactly would you like the conversion to work?
Do you simply want an array containing the ASCII value of each character in the array? (so "abc" becomes [97, 98, 99, 0])?

Or do you want to parse the string somehow? ("1, 2, 3" becomes an array [1, 2, 3])

In the first case, in C++, I'd do something like this:

```
struct convert {
  int operator()(char c) {
    return static_cast<int>(c);
  }
};

std::string str = "hello world";
std::vector<int> result;
std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), std::back_inserter(result), convert())
```

Of course you could use a raw array instead of the vector, but since the length of the string is probably going to be variable, and then arrays are just asking for trouble.

If this wasn't what you wanted, you might want to edit your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, for input string "110013" would be converted to array {1,1,0,0,1,3}. Here is how to do it in C++:

```
string a = "1110011000";
vector<int> v;
for(int i = 0 ; i < a.length() ; i++){
    v.push_back(a[i] -'0');
}

// Check the result
for(int i = 0 ; i < v.size() ; i++){
    cout << v[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Although this is obvious to experienced C programmers, I might point out that the "trick" is a[i]-'0'.  It relies on the fact that ASCII representation of numbers are next to each other, so '0' is NOT 0, but it is guaranteed to always be exactly 1 less than '1'

Answer (score 1):

Quick string splitter routine:

```
convert(string str, string delim, vector<int>& results)
{
  int next;
  char buf[20];
  while( (next= str.find_first_of(delim)) != str.npos ) {
    if (next> 0) 
      results.push_back(atoi(str.substr(0,next), buf, 10));
    str = str.substr(next+1);
  }
  if(str.length() > 0)
    results.push_back(atoi(str.substr(0,next), buf, 10));
}
```

You can use stringstream instead of atoi (which does work, on a single int at a time)

```
int i;
stringstream s (input_string)
s >> i;
```

If you combine my and jalf's code, you'll get something really good.

Answer (score 1):

Use the istream_iterator in conjunction with a string stream.

By Array I am assuming you really mean a std::vector as you don't know the number of integers at compile time. But the code can easily be modified to use an array rather than a vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string         data = "5 6 7 8 9";
    std::stringstream   dataStream(data);
    std::vector<int>    store(
                            std::istream_iterator<int>(dataStream),
                            std::istream_iterator<int>{}
                        );

    // This line just copies the store to the std::cout
    // To verify it worked.
    std::copy(store.begin(),
              store.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout,",")
             );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Language: C

Header:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Function Prototype:

```
long int strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);
```

Example Usage:

```
strtol(nptr, (char **) NULL, 10);
```